# R set variable equal to what function returns. Re-evaluate variable again each time it is called

Tags: r, variables, dynamic, environment, scoping

I'm not a developer, and I can't express well what I need in simple words. It is connected to things like environments, scoping, enclosure, and perhaps pointers and references.

It should be clear with code:

```
a<-c(1,2)
b<-length(a)
a<-c(1,2,3)
b
[1] 2
```

I want b to return 3.

What do I change in the second line? Is it possible to do it without defining new custom functions and using external packages?

Failed trying eval, assign, <<- so far

Answer (score 6):

I'm not recommending that you should actually use it, but `makeActiveBinding()` will do what you're asking for:

```
makeActiveBinding("b", function() length(a), .GlobalEnv)
a <- c(1,2)
b
# [1] 2
a <- c(1,2,4)
b
# [1] 3
```

Comment: Amazing. What's the best source of information (e.g. book) where I can read more about it (except obviously for just googling binding). Are there any "synonyms" of that binding in other programming languages or related topics? I would also like to use something similar in shell scripts - is it also called binding in bash?.

Comment: Hmm. Not sure. The basic idea, though, is that behind the scenes, typing `b` runs the function `length(a)` every time it's evaluated. Personally, I'd be much more comfortable just defining a simple function `b <- function() length(a)` and then doing `b()` (rather than `b`) to get the length of `a`. That way you sidestep whatever murky magic is really going on behind the scenes with what even `?makeActiveBinding` describes as "an experimental interface". By just typing the additional `()`, you can stay in the more mainstream world of simple function definitions and function calls.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien - I'd add that to the answer rather than leaving it here in the comments. Everything you said seems pretty wise to me.